# How show javascript object as html tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, treeview, javascript-objects, hierarchy

I would like to generate a tree from the following object:

configuration:

```
  {
    name: "General",
    icon: "general",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Line 1",
        icon: "line",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Area 1",
            icon: "area",
            children: [
              { name: "Y", icon: "x" },
              { name: "Z", icon: "z" },
            ],
          },
          { name: "Area 2", icon: "line" },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Line 2,
        icon: "line",
        children: [{ name: "Area 3", icon: "area" }],
      },
    ],
  },
```

In html I have my own custom element:

```
<my-details>
            <div slot="summary"><my-icon name="${icon}"></my-icon> ${name}</div>
            ${this.children} // ???
</my-details>`;
```

so I created the function:

```
 createHierarchy() {
    if (configuration?.length > 0) {
      const details = _configuration.map(({ name, icon }) => {
        return ` <my-details>
            <div slot="summary"><my-icon name="${icon}"></my-icon> ${name}</div>
            ${this.children}
           </my-details>`;
      });

      hierarchyContainer.innerHTML = details?.join("");
    }
  }
```

but I don't know how to convert this structure in a loop or map to a tree, each element of the hierarchy should be a my-details element and have a name as a slot and in the middle it should have children

the structure should look like this:
[hierarchy tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTwZn.png)

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. Is it a JavaScript object instead? Don't use the JSON tag for JavaScript object literals.

Comment: yes sorry, it's not json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a *recursive* function. Which is a function that calls itself.

It should end up looking something like this:

```js
function parseNode(node) {
  let html = `<my-details>
    <div slot="summary">
       <my-icon name="${node.icon}"></my-icon>
       ${node.name}. 
    </div>`;
  if(node.children) {
    node.children.forEach(childNode => {
      html += parseNode(childNode);
    })
  ;}
  html += '</my-details>';
  return html;
}

parseNode(configuration);
```

This example turns your entire configuration into an html string (or it should it is untested). You can output to your document/component.

Note that it relies on all nodes having a name and an icon and a possible "children" has to be an array.